# Question has reopen/close votes but does not appear in my reopen/close review queue?

Tags: bug, reopen-queue, review-queue

I notice that [this question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/67425/how-to-protect-a-server-from-ddos-attacks) has been put on hold and has 1 reopen vote.

However, the question does not appear in my [Reopen Review Queue](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/review/reopen) (which appears empty). Why?

I have noticed this a few times in the past.

I could click on the link in the question itself, but otherwise I would not know that there was a question with reopen votes, since the relevant review queue appears empty?

---

**UPDATE 2016-11-11** : As mentioned in comments, this (still) happens with Close Votes as well. For example, take [this recent question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/101021/301-redirects-from-httphttps-naked-domain-www-not-working-on-atts-4g-netw), which is currently showing 1 close vote below the question itself:

[image: Close vote under question]

However, this question has not appeared in the Close Votes review queue (as far as I can tell), which is currently empty.

[image: Empty Close Votes review queue]

This is despite waiting 9+ hours. (I happened to notice the close vote after the first hour the question was asked. The next day, the situation remains the same.)

**UPDATE 2016-11-20** : Another question that has a close vote and doesn't appear in my close votes review queue: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/101280/nginx-sending-different-cors-headers-for-get-vs-post-request

Comment: I can confirm this also occurs with Close Votes and Suggested Edits, even after waiting a half hour or more and clearing my browser's cache. Additionally sometimes I'll perform a review task and it will not be listed under the review history, for any user. I typically use Chrome, and sometimes Firefox.

Comment: The referenced question was deleted by the owner, however the problem still exists for other questions that have been edited by the OP, voted closed, or has suggested edits.

Answer (score 1):

One pattern I have noticed is that a question (which has received close votes) does not seem to appear in the (my) close votes queue if I have provided an answer to that question. This is shown with the following two recent questions:

- [Properly redirect a site to WWW and HTTPS](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/104475/properly-redirect-a-site-to-www-and-https) (1 close vote)
- [.htaccess to WWW And/Or HTTPS](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/104474/htaccess-to-www-and-or-https) (1 close vote)

This may just be a coincidence (or simply one instance of), as with other questions mentioned above I have not provided an answer (or commented).

Comment: The above questions were reviewed by moderators under the "Close Votes" section of the Review queue;  the first [one](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/review/close/47635) by John, and the second [one](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/review/close/47633) by myself. Votes by moderators are considered final, but close votes by users may still show up under the question, but not in the Review queue, if they've been handled by a moderator first. I believe this is because if the question receives enough votes (5) by the community, it can still be closed, reopened, or deleted.